# I am getting an error while using bubble sort in array of structures not able to find it

Tags: c, sorting, structure

I am having a structure

```
typedef struct ratings {
    int userId;
    int movieId;
    int rating;
}Ratings;
```

I am using bubble sort to sort as per my choice

```
Ratings rect[64], temp;
      n = 64;

   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
{

   for (j = 0; j < (n - i -1); j++)
    {
      if (REC1[j].movieId >= REC1[j+1].movieId)
       {
         temp = REC1[j];
         REC1[j] = REC1[j + 1];
         REC1[j + 1] = temp;
      }
   }
}

 for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
{

   for (j = 0; j < (n - i -1); j++)
    {
      if(REC1[j].movieId == REC1[j+1].movieId ) 
      {
        if (REC1[j].userId >= REC1[j+1].userId)
        {
          temp = REC1[j];
          REC1[j] = REC1[j + 1];
          REC1[j + 1] = temp;
        }
     }

   }
}
```

i used the above logic to get my output and succeeded. Can it be reduced to less???? Please try it 
my inputs are

```
    1,1,9
    1,2,0
    1,3,2
    2,1,2
    2,2,10
    2,3,10
    3,1,7
    3,2,1
    3,3,9
```

i want the output as

```
1,1,9
2,1,2
3,1,7
1,2,0
2,2,10
3,2,1
1,3,2
2,3,10
3,3,9
```

for this i am using my above logic of sorting still not getting the result
[This is the output i am getting but i need a the above output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EQay.png)

Comment: The `Ratings` I can see is not an array, it is a `type`.

Comment: It looks like you intend to have an array (or pointer) named `Ratings`, but it has already been declared as a type.  Pick a *different* name, and declare it.  Compile-time errors are usually pretty clear, so try to get your code to at least compile.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] so we don't need to guess.

Comment: @Sam please post the complete code that causes trouble. This is called a [MCVE] (more or less).

Comment: @MichaelWalz sir have edited the same. Used the bubble sort logic still not getting the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already declared `Ratings` as a type of `struct ratings`.

Hence you should declare a array of structure like below

```
Ratings myratings[100], temp;

if (myratings[i].movieId > myratings[j].movieId)
       {
         temp = myratings[j];/* it might not work if you are not compiling with a C++ compiler better use memcpy function if you are using a C compiler */
         myratings[j] = myratings[j + 1];
         myratings[j + 1] = temp;
      }
```

Please correct your bubble short algorithm like below:-

```
for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
{

   for (j = 0; j < (n - i -1); j++)
    {
      if (rect[j].movieId > rect[j+1].movieId)
       {
         temp = rect[j];
         rect[j] = rect[j + 1];
         rect[j + 1] = temp;
      }
   }
}
```

if you want to swap value only not the object it should be like
     int t;

```
//This is bubble sort for middle row
for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
{

   for (j = 0; j < (n - i -1); j++)
    {
      if (rect[j].movieId > rect[j+1].movieId)
      {
         t = rect[j].movieId;
         rect[j].movieId = rect[j+1].movieId;
         rect[j+1].movieId = t;
      }

   }
}

 //This is bubble sort for 1st row

for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
{

   for (j = 0; j < (n - i -1); j++)
    {
      if (rect[j].userId > rect[j+1].userId)
      {
         t = rect[j].userId;
         rect[j].userId = rect[j+1].userId;
         rect[j+1].userId = t;
      }

   }
}

//This is bubble sort for 3rd row


for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
{

   for (j = 0; j < (n - i -1); j++)
    {
      if (rect[j].rating > rect[j+1].rating)
      {
         t = rect[j].rating;
         rect[j].rating = rect[j+1].rating;
         rect[j+1].rating = t;
      }

   }
}
```

you have to add all the above three while loop in your code

Comment: @Sam, Your bubble sort algorithm is not correct. Please see the corrected one that I have added to my answer in my code.

Comment: @Sam, I have just corrected my code it should now work.

Comment: @Sam, what are your comparing here `rect[j].movieId > rect[j+1].movieId` you are only shorting based on 2nd column. You are swapping the object not the value in it. It simply sort the 2nd column only

Comment: @Sam, remove your `for` loop with above newly added 3 `for` loops in my code, it will sort all the column. If you don't want to sort the 3rd column just add first 2 `for` loops from my code. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

The `typedef` keyword in

```
typedef struct ratings {
    int userId;
    int movieId;
    int rating;
}Ratings, temp;
```

defines `Ratings` and `temp` as *aliases* for the type `struct ratings`, not as *objects* of the type `struct ratings`.  What you want to do is something like

```
struct ratings {
  int userId;
  int movieId;
  int rating;
};

struct ratings Ratings[N], temp; // where N is the size of the array you want.
```

*or*

```
typedef struct ratings {
    int userId;
    int movieId;
    int rating;
}Ratings;

Ratings myRatings[N], temp;
```

I prefer the first form, myself.  I'd rather not hide a `struct` type behind a `typedef` if the user of the type has to be aware of its `struct`-ness (i.e., having to access individual members).

Comment: thank you i have  corrected that, still not getting my output.

Comment: @Sam: Not getting any output *at all*, or getting output that isn't sorted the way you want it to be?  You don't show your output code, so it's anyone's guess why it wouldn't be working.

Comment: @Sam: Don't post a link to an image of your output - I'm not going to click on a random link.  Copy and paste the output into your question.